# Using python argparse to add data(records) into SQLite Database

Tags: python, sqlite, argparse

I'm creating file tracking script(python) with SQLite Database, that my coworkers can run the script to store their files into the db, and later Query & Update from the db. In a nutshell there could be multiple `FfAMILY` File_Family with the same name, and each File_Family can have multiple Folders, and Files.
When users run my script they pass a `FfAMILY` File_Family along with its `FOLDER` Folder, created Date `DATE`, its directory under Path `PATH`, its Filename `FNAME`, if more than one Filename exists with the same name they also provide how many under Chunks `CHUNKS`, its MD5 Sum `MD5` and if compressed, Zipped file is added `ZIP`.

I don't want File_Family to be unique I want users to add however many `FOLDER, DATE, PATH, FNAME, CHUNKS, MD5, ZIP` they want under the same File_Family name.

```
import argparse
import sys
import sqlite3

debug = 1

def main():

    # Creating a parser object
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "This program will read values into sqlite table.")
    
    # Adding argument
    parser.add_argument("FfAMILY", help = "Adds to database FILE_FAMILY Column")
    parser.add_argument("FOLDER", help = "Adds to database FOLDER Column")
    parser.add_argument("DATE", help = "Adds to database DATE Column")
    parser.add_argument("PATH", help = "Adds to database PATH Column")
    parser.add_argument("FNAME", help = "Adds to database FILENAME Column")
    parser.add_argument("CHUNKS", help = "Adds to database CHUNKS Column")
    parser.add_argument("MD5", help = "Adds to database MD5 Column")
    parser.add_argument("ZIP", help = "Adds to database ZIP Column")

    # Parse the arguments from standard input
    args= parser.parse_args()

    for arg in vars(args):
        print(arg, getattr(args, arg))
   
   
    # Database connection
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Collection.db")  
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    
    
    # create table function for Track_Collection
    def CreateTable():
        cmd =  """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Track_Collection 
                (FfAMILY TEXT,
                FOLDER TEXT,
                DATE INTEGER,
                PATH TEXT,
                FNAME TEXT,
                CHUNKS INTEGER,
                MD5 INTEGER,
                ZIP TEXT
                )"""
        cur.execute(cmd)
        conn.commit()
        
        if debug:
            print("Create Table Run!")
    
    
    def InsertToTable(File_Family, Folder, Date, Path, Filename, Chunks, MD5, Zip):
        cur.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Track_Collection (FfAMILY, FOLDER, DATE, PATH, FNAME, CHUNKS, MD5, ZIP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (File_Family, Folder, Date, Path, Filename, Chunks, MD5, Zip))
        
        conn.commit()
        
        if debug:
            print("Insert Table run!")
               
    # Invoking creation of Track_Collection
    CreateTable()
        
# I want to be able to add data to specific column and push db row      
    for arg in vars (args):
        if arg == "FfAMILY":
            File_Family = getattr(args, arg)
        elif arg == "FOLDER":
            Folder = getattr(args, arg)
          elif arg == "DATE":
            Date = getattr(args, arg)
        elif arg == "PATH":
            Path = getattr(args, arg)
        elif arg == "FNAME":
            Filename = getattr(args, arg)            
        elif arg == "CHUNKS":
            Chunks = getattr(args, arg)
        elif arg == "MD5":
            MD5 = getattr(args, arg)
        elif arg == "ZIP":
            Zip= getattr(args, arg)
        else:
            print(arg)
            parser.print_help()
    
    # Invoking InsertToTable
    InsertToTable(File_Family, Folder, Date, Path, Filename, Chunks, MD5, Zip)
    
    # close connection to the database
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() 
    print("Program Finished!!")
```

If you are able to run my script you will see that it can parse all the args and store it into SQLite db.
However, that's only how far I was able to go.
In order for this to be complete I need help adding Query feature, for example; if I query `Ffamily` File_Family I should get lists of all the Folders, Date, Filename, etc. AND I also need help adding an Update feature
that takes an argument from Terminal and select a specific File_Family, and a specific Folder in that File_Family to update/add more files `FILENAME`, for example; from the Terminal it should take this kind of argument  `updateDb -FOLDER <->`

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want help to add functionality to your script?

Comment: You've descibed the ideas you have, but not an actual problem you're stuck on - that's not a good question to ask on StackOverflow (welcome, by the way). Please restrict your questions to concrete questions, that people can answer - don't ask for suggestions or expect people to write your code for you. I will say this: you'll find that, once you add some complexity, you're just redoing a query language and you'll end up realising you could just pass SQL queries on the command line.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77190888/im-trying-to-write-a-python-program-that-takes-parser-arguments-from-users-and ?

Comment: With that `parser`, you don't need all the ifs, just use `File_Family=args.Ffamily`, etc.  The current parser requires your user specify 8 strings, which you access as `args` attributes.  To allow some sort of 'action', you may need to use one or more flagged argument, or use the subparsers mechanism.

Comment: I think you need to experiment with some of simpler examples in the `argparse` docs.  Pay attention to what the `print(args)` shows for different setups.  Try a mix of flagged ('optionals') and positional arguments.  Once you get a desired mix of `args` outputs, you can move on to performing the SQL commands.  `argparse` is primarily a way of figuring out what your user wants.  Acting on those wants is the job of your own code logic.